# Updating an Array of Checkboxes based on a hidden field (and vice versa) with the binary representation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have on my form a group of checkboxes that belong together. The number of checkboxes is fixed, let's say 8. There is also a hidden Input field. When the page loads, I want the checkboxes to update so that they show the binary representation of the hidden value (should be unsigned integer).

E.g. on load the value of the hidden field is 123, therefor the field of checkboxes look like this:

> [ ][X][X][X][X][ ][X][X]

If a checkbox then is altered the hidden value should be updated.

E.g. after the last checkbox is clicked (and thereby turned off):

> [ ][X][X][X][X][ ][X][ ]

-> Hidden value: 122

```
<input name="test[0]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[2]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[3]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[4]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[5]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[6]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[7]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="realValue" type="hidden" value="123">
```

The Idea is, that I can then simply save a whole set of (very similar) binary options in just one int field in my database, without creating a bazillion boolean fields.

I guess there is a JS library that can do exactly that, but I couldn't find something.. Does someone have a simple solution?

Comment: This sounds like a number that would be much simpler to compute server side once the checkboxes were submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check check each of the bits in turn by using the bitwise and (`&`) and you can toggle a bit at a specific index by applying the bitwise XOR (`^`) at `1 << index`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=test]');
const realVal = document.querySelector('#realValue');
function changeVal(){
  let curr = +realVal.value;
  for(let i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    inputs[i].checked = curr & 1 === 1;
    curr >>= 1;
  }
}
changeVal();
inputs.forEach((input, index) => input.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  realVal.value = +realVal.value ^ (1 << (inputs.length - index - 1));
}));
```

```html
<input name="test[0]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[2]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[3]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[4]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[5]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[6]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="test[7]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="realValue" value="123">
```